# read bmp from sd card faster

Tags: sd-card, bmp, spiffs

i am working on Cy8CKIT -050 cypress kit, flash chip W25Q128FV ,SD card, and TFT display https://www.buydisplay.com/default/lcd-5-ssd1963-tft-module-touch-screen-display-800x480-mcu-arduino

i have interfaced display, flash chip using SPIFFS and sd card using FATFS with Cy8CKIT - 050

but the speed of BMP image loading from the sd card is very slow, right now size of image is 150*90 and its taking 635ms

how can i improve this?
also i want write BMP image from the sd card to Flash chip and load image from flash chip to display, how can i do that

i am attaching code for reference

`void DrawImage(UG_S16 x1, UG_S16 y1, UG_S16 x2, UG_S16 y2, const TCHAR* namefile)
{

```
FATFS fatFs;
FIL fileO;
uint16_t buffimg,buffimg1;
uint16_t buffer[1];
UINT br,br1;
FRESULT pt;
char read[50];

uint32_t bmpWidth  = 0;
uint32_t bmpHeight = 0;
uint16_t bmpImageoffset;
uint16_t rowSize;
uint8_t rdBuf[60];
uint8_t header_buff[60];
uint16_t position = 0;
uint8_t numberOfPixels = 0;
uint32_t commpression = 0;
uint32_t imageSize = 0;
unsigned int byte_read;
uint16_t bmpSig;
uint8_t row_buff[rowSize]; // only read 1 row at a time 
uint8_t cc,R,G,B;
uint16_t pixel; 
uint16_t color;   
uint32 i,j, count=0;
uint8_t pColorData[DISPLAY_WIDTH*3];
uint8_t pColorData_flash[DISPLAY_WIDTH*3];
uint8_t pColorData_flash1[DISPLAY_WIDTH*3];


uint32_t pos;
int row =0 ;



if((x1 < 0) ||(x1 >= DISPLAY_WIDTH) || (y1 < 0) || (y1 >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT)) return;
if((x2 < 0) ||(x2 >= DISPLAY_WIDTH) || (y2 < 0) || (y2 >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT)) return;




/* Mount drive */
 pt = f_mount(&fatFs, "", 1);
if(pt != FR_OK) return;

/* open file */
pt = f_open(&fileO, namefile, FA_READ);
if(pt != FR_OK) return;

/* read bmp header */
pt = f_read(&fileO, header_buff, sizeof header_buff, &byte_read); 

if(pt != FR_OK){

    return;
}


//my_spiffs_mount();

//spiffs_file fd = SPIFFS_open(&fs, "bmpFile", SPIFFS_CREAT | SPIFFS_TRUNC | SPIFFS_RDWR, 0);
//if (SPIFFS_write(&fs, fd,header_buff, sizeof(header_buff)) < 0) sprintf(bufferOut,"wr errno %i\n", SPIFFS_errno(&fs));
//SPIFFS_close(&fs, fd); 
//UG_PutString(1,200,bufferOut);

//fd = SPIFFS_open(&fs, "bmpFile", SPIFFS_RDWR, 0);
//if (SPIFFS_read(&fs, fd, rdBuf, sizeof(rdBuf)) < 0) sprintf(bufferOut,"rd errno %i\n", SPIFFS_errno(&fs));
//SPIFFS_close(&fs, fd);
//UG_PutString(1,220,bufferOut);


bmpSig = (header_buff[1] << 8) | header_buff [0];
sprintf(bufferOut,"Signature:\t0x%X\n", bmpSig);
UG_PutString(1,160,bufferOut);
if(bmpSig != 0x4D42){
    UG_PutString(1,180,"not a bmp");
    return; // not a bmp
}
bmpImageoffset =  header_buff  [7] * 256 + header_buff  [6];
bmpHeight =  (header_buff  [25] << 24) | (header_buff  [24] << 16) | (header_buff  [23] << 8) | header_buff  [22];
bmpWidth = (header_buff  [21] << 24) |  (header_buff  [20] << 16) | (header_buff  [19] << 8) | header_buff  [18];
position = header_buff  [10]; // starting point in file
numberOfPixels = header_buff  [29] * 256 + header_buff  [28];
commpression = (header_buff  [30] << 24) |  (header_buff  [31] << 16) | (header_buff  [32] << 8) | header_buff  [33];
imageSize = (header_buff  [37] << 24) |  (header_buff  [36] << 16) | (header_buff  [35] << 8) | header_buff  [34];

rowSize = ((numberOfPixels * bmpWidth + 31) /32 ) * 4;


sprintf(read ,"Offset:\t%d\n", bmpImageoffset);
    UG_PutString(1,1,read);

sprintf(read ,"Height:\t%u\n", bmpHeight);
    UG_PutString(1,20,read);

sprintf(read ,"Width:\t\t%u\n", bmpWidth);
    UG_PutString(1,40,read);

sprintf(read ,"Row Size:\t%d\n", rowSize);
    UG_PutString(1,60,read);

sprintf(read ,"Start Index:\t%d\n", position);
    UG_PutString(1,80,read);

sprintf(read ,"# of Pixels:\t%d\n", numberOfPixels);
    UG_PutString(1,100,read);

sprintf(read ,"Compression:\t%u\n", commpression);
    UG_PutString(1,120,read);

sprintf(read ,"Image Size:\t%u\n", imageSize);
    UG_PutString(1,140,read);
```

Display_WindowSet(x1, x2, y1, y2);

/* Write to LCD-GRAM */
   Display_WriteCommand(0x2c);

/* get current millisecond count  */
   unsigned long nCurrentMillis = nmillis;

```
   for(i=0;i<bmpHeight; i++)  
    {
        for(j=0; j<rowSize; j++)                                                        
        {               
            count++;
            LED3_Write(1);

            f_read(&fileO,pColorData+j,1,&byte_read);

            //fd = SPIFFS_open(&fs, "bmpFile", SPIFFS_RDWR , 0);
            //if (SPIFFS_write(&fs, fd,pColorData+j, 1) < 0) sprintf(bufferOut,"wr errno %i\n", SPIFFS_errno(&fs));
            //SPIFFS_close(&fs, fd); 


            //fd = SPIFFS_open(&fs, "bmpFile", SPIFFS_RDWR, 0);
            //if (SPIFFS_read(&fs, fd, pColorData_flash+j, 1) < 0) sprintf(bufferOut,"rd errno %i\n", SPIFFS_errno(&fs));
            //SPIFFS_close(&fs, fd);

            //sprintf(bufferOut," row %lu",j);
            //UG_PutString(1,360,bufferOut);


           //CyDelay(1);
            LED3_Write(0);

        }                               
        for(j=0;j<bmpWidth;j++)                                                                 
        {
            //fd = SPIFFS_open(&fs, "bmpFile", SPIFFS_RDWR, 0);
            //if (SPIFFS_read(&fs, fd, pColorData_flash,rowSize) < 0) sprintf(bufferOut,"rd errno %i\n", SPIFFS_errno(&fs));
            //SPIFFS_close(&fs, fd);

            uint32_t k = j*3;                                                                               
            R = pColorData[k+2];
            G = pColorData[k+1];
            B = pColorData[k];

            color = color565(R,G,B);
            Display_WriteData (color);  

            //sprintf(bufferOut," width %lu",j);
            //UG_PutString(1,380,bufferOut);

        }
            //sprintf(bufferOut," height %lu",i);
            //UG_PutString(1,400,bufferOut);
```

}

```
unsigned long nTime = nmillis-nCurrentMillis;
sprintf(bufferOut,"time taken for load : %lu ms",nTime);
UG_PutString(1,320,bufferOut);
sprintf(bufferOut,"%lu",count);
UG_PutString(1,340,bufferOut);
f_close(&fileO);
```

}
`

Comment: Calling `f_read` for every byte of pixel data seems like a bad idea. I don't know how your FatFs implementation works internally (i.e. if it's caching sectors, etc), but that's still a lot of unnecessary function calls. I'd try to read as much pixel data per `f_read` call as I could fit into RAM.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: it would be very help full if you guide, because i am completely new in this work

Comment: Just read data from the file in larger chunks and process it from memory, instead of reading each byte individually.

Comment: any code example?

Comment: solved by reading the whole single row at once